# Give value to an organ in an associative array - php

Tags: php, arrays

I try to turn an organ in an associative array into an array, but it fails in this way:

```
$arr = array('1' => '2','10' => '2');

$arr['1']['10'] = '3';

var_dump($arr);

$arr['1']['5'] = array('4' => 5);

var_dump($arr);
```

results:

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  string(11) "2         3"
  [10]=>
  string(1) "2"
}
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  string(11) "2    A    3"
  [10]=>
  string(1) "2"
}
```

Is it possible at all?

Comment: That is the correct result for the code you wrote. What exactly where you expecting instead? And what is an "organ" in this context?

Comment: I gotta admit I have no clue what you're trying to achieve. What is an organ here? Can you explain a little more?

Comment: trafficking in human organs is illegal

Comment: @FlashThunder maybe it's a hammond organ?? ;-)

Comment: I would expect when I call $ arr ['1'] that he will point to his value, And when I call $ arr ['1'] ['5'] it will turn it into an associative array

Comment: Really hard to tell what you are trying to ask here. It looks like you are trying to make the entry under key `1`, which is currently a string value (`2`), into an array? With `$arr['1']['10'] = '3';`, PHP treats the `10` as a _string_ index, because `$arr['1']` is a string value already - that’s why you get `string(11) "2         3"` in the result. If you want to change this element into an array, then that should start by assigning an (empty) array to `$arr['1']`.

Comment: _"it will turn it into an associative array"_ ... No that's not how it works. $arr[1] is already a string. So when you write `$arr['1']['5']` it will point to index 5 in that existing string value (because strings have indexes which refer to each individual character in the string). It doesn't convert anything, it works on what's already there and alters it.

Comment: Also "turn it into an associative array" still doesn't fully describe what result you want. What should happen to the existing value of $arr[1] at that time? Where should the `2` go? Should it be destroyed? or should it be placed into some other index in the new array? Please clarify.

Comment: I want to turn the string into a key that will contain an array within it, and It is interesting that a text responds both as a simple array and as an associative array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the commented line:

```
<?php
$arr = array('1' => '2','10' => '2');
# BAD
$arr['1']['10'] = '3';
```

At the time you are calling this line, `$arr['1']` is a String, not an array.
So if you want to treat it as an array, then you will need to declare it as
such:

```
<?php
$arr = array('1' => '2','10' => '2');
$arr['1'] = [];
$arr['1']['10'] = '3';
```

However this may not be what you want, as youve just destroyed the previous
value there (String `2`).

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing the idea of associative arrays and multi-dimensional arrays here.

Here you create a single-dimensional association array

```
$arr = array('1' => '2','10' => '2');
```

Next, you add another entry to the entry that has the "key" of '1'

```
$arr['1']['10'] = '3';
```

This works as expected.  Since $arr['1'] is the string value '2' a string offset of 10 is performed and the string '3' is inserted at position 10.  To further elaborate this if you then added

```
$arr['1']['12'] = '5';
```

Then var_dump($arr); would display

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  string(13) "2         3 5"
  [10]=>
  string(1) "2"
}
```

You should see here that '5' has been appended to the string at position 12 and the rest of the string has been padded out with spaces.

If I understand what you are wanting to do and create a multi-dimensional array then it would need to look more like this.

```
$arr = array('1' => array('2', '10' => '2'));
```

Now the key '1' is an index to another array.  Within that array is contained the string value '2' at index 0 and the string value '2' keyed to '10'.

```
var_dump($arr);
```

reveals we now have a nested array

```
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [10]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
}
```

Now you can add additional entries to the nested array as desired.

```
$arr['1']['11'] = 'foo';
```

for example, would result in the following if you were to var_dump($arr)

```
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [10]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [11]=>
    string(3) "foo"
  }
}
```